# Where should I code cordova's onDeviceReady function in meteor?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I am doing meteor mobile app for android. I installed [this](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.oauth2) plugin by `meteor add cordova:org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.oauth2@1.0.3`. Now I want to run `onDeviceReady` function. I tried this function in both `Meteor.isCordova` and `Meteor.startup`. It doesn't work. I don't know weather my approach is right? And where should I code?

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  oauth2.addFacebook({
    name: 'facebook',
    settings: {
      clientId: '1511044619160050',
      clientSecret: '3b08052d3d96e2120f2c53a36eebd02f',
      scopes: 'photo_upload, publish_actions'
    }
  });
}
```

ReferenceError: `oauth2` is not defined

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please checkout the code @rubikonx9. I edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Meteor.startup`:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    oauth2.addFacebook({
      name: 'facebook',
        settings: {
          clientId: '1511044619160050',
          clientSecret: '3b08052d3d96e2120f2c53a36eebd02f',
          scopes: 'photo_upload, publish_actions'
        }
     });
   }
});
```

From: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

> Any functionality which relies on a Cordova/Phonegap plugin should
>   wrap code in a Meteor.startup() block.

While not mentioned explicitly, it fires after the `onDeviceReady` event. Verified in the meteor source @ https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/29194cef83d418227a8cc43e41b1539b13a6b68a/packages/meteor/startup_client.js#L12-L27